# i am simulating CTMC using Gillespie Algorithm for dynamics of leprosy using 10 compartment ,encounter an error when closing my bracket after simdat,i

Tags: r

```r
abcdefghij.onestep <- function (x, params) {
    Susceptible <- x[2]
    Exposed <- x[3]
    Infected_Multibacillary <- x[4]
    Infected_Paucibacillary <- x[5]
    Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis <- x[6]
    Treated <- x[7]
    Disability <- x[8]
    Recovered <- x[9]
    Relapse_Multibacillary <-x[10]
    Relapse_Paucibacillary <-x[11]
    N <- Susceptible + Exposed + Infected_Multibacillary + Infected_Paucibacillary + Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis + Treated + Disability + Recovered + Relapse_Multibacillary + Relapse_Paucibacillary
    m12 <- params["m12"]
    m25 <- params["m25"]
    m23 <- params["m23"]
    m24 <- params["m24"]
    m35 <- params["m35"]
    m45 <- params["m45"]
    m37 <- params["m37"]
    m56 <- params["m56"]
    m67 <- params["m67"]
    m68 <- params["m68"]
    m89 <- params["m89"]
    m810 <- params["m810"]
    m96 <- params["m96"]
    m97 <- params["m97"]
    m106 <- params["m106"]
    mu <- params["mu"]
    rates <- c(
        birth=mu*N, susceptible_exposed=m12*Susceptible*Infected_Multibacillary -m25*Infected_Multibacillary * Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis -m23*Exposed*Infected_Multibacillary -m24*Exposed*Infected_Paucibacillary,
        exposed_infected_multibacillary=m23*Exposed*Infected_Paucibacillary-m35*Infected_Multibacillary*Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis-m45* Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis* Infected_Paucibacillary-m37*Disability*Infected_Multibacillary,
        exposed_infected_paucibacillary=m24*Exposed*Infected_Paucibacillary-m45*Infected_Paucibacillary*Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis,
        infected_multibacillary_exposed_detected=m35*Infected_Multibacillary*Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis+m45*Infected_Paucibacillary* Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis-m56* Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis*Treated,
        exposed_detected_treatment=m56*Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis*Treated-m67*Treated* Disability-m68*Treated*Recovered,
        infected_multibacillary_disability=m37*Disability*Infected_Multibacillary+m67*Treated* Disability,
        treated_recovered=m68* Treated*Recovered-m89*Recovered*Infected_Multibacillary-m810* Recovered*Infected_Paucibacillary,
        relapse_multibacillary_treatment=-m96*Relapse_Multibacillary* Treated-m97*Relapse_Multibacillary*Disability,
        relapse_paucibacillary_treatment=-m106*Relapse_Paucibacillary*Treated,
        susceptible_death=mu*Susceptible,
        exposed_death=mu*Exposed,
        infected_multibacillary_death=mu*Infected_Multibacillary,
        infected_paucibacillary_death=mu*Infected_Paucibacillary,
        exposed_detected_death=mu* Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis,
        treatment_death=mu*Treated,
        disability_death=mu*Disability,
        recovered_death=mu*Recovered,
        relapse_multibacillary_death=mu*Relapse_Multibacillary,
        relapse_paucibacillary_death=mu*Relapse_Paucibacilary
    )
    transitions <- list(
        birth=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        susceptible_exposed=c(-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        exposed_infected_multibacillary=c(0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        exposed_infected_paucibacillary=c(0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        infected_multibacillary_exposed_detected=c(0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
        exposed_detected_treatment=c(0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0),
        infected_multibacillary_disability=c(0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
        treated_recovered=c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0),
        relapse_multibacillary_treatment=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0),
        relapse_paucibacillary_treatment=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1),
        susceptible_death=c(-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        exposed_death= c(0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        infected_multibacillary_death= c(0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        infected_paucibacillary_death= c(0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        exposed_detected_death= c(0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0),
        treatment_death= c(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0),
        disability_death= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0),
        recovered_death= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0),
        relapse_multibacillary_death= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0),
        relapse_paucibacillary_death= c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1)
    )
    total.rate <- sum(rates)
    if (total.rate==0)
        tau <- Inf
    else
        tau <- rexp(n=1,rate=total.rate)
    event <- sample.int(n=6,size=1,prob=rates/total.rate)
    x+c(tau,transitions[[event]])
}
abcdefghij.simul <- function (x, params, maxstep = 10000) {
    output <- array(dim=c(maxstep+1,4))
    colnames(output) <- names(x)
    output[1,] <-x
    k <- 1
    while ((k <= maxstep) && (x["Exposed"] > 0)) {
        k <- k+1
        output[k,] <- x <- abcdefghij.onestep(x,params)
    }
    as.data.frame(output[1:k,])
}
```

And in R this happens:

```
> set.seed(56856583)
> nsims <- 1
> xstart <- c(time=1,Susceptible=100000,Exposed=1,Infected_Multibacillary=1,Infected_Paucibacillary=1,Exposed_Detected_Diagnosis=1,Treated=1,Disability=1,Recovered=1,Relapse_Multibacillary=1,Relapse_Paucibacillary=1)
> library(plyr)
> simdat <- rdply(nsims, abcdefghij.simul(xstart,params))
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Called from: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(x))
Browse[1]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
output <- array(dim=c(maxstep+1,4))
```

To this instead:

```
output <- array(dim=c(maxstep+1,11))
```

Your `xstart` variable has 11 elements. If you want them all on one row, you have to create something that is 11 columns wide, not 4. Perhaps you had just 4 values in the beginning.

Furthermore you don't seem to define `params` anywhere. The code won't run until you do.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate

Comment: > simdat <- rdply(nsims, abcdefghij.simul(xstart,params)
+ )
Error in list(birth = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), susceptible_exposed = c(-1,  : 
  argument 21 is empty
Called from: abcdefghij.onestep(x, params)
Browse[1]>

Comment: make sure you don't have any vectors or lists wit commas followed by nothing. did you change the code from what you uploaded?

Comment: ok, Thanks. But it also show me this error

Comment: I don't get that error. What you have is a syntax error that likely isn't in the code you have pasted, could you make sure you run code as shown above, only with ,4 changed to ,11 as explained?

Comment: i did that, what is showing now is this:Error in if (total.rate == 0) tau <- Inf else tau <- rexp(n = 1, rate = total.rate) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: when i run the code early with 4 instead 11, it give this error message: Error in if (total.rate == 0) tau <- Inf else tau <- rexp(n = 1, rate = total.rate) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Could you help me run the code for me please